# Конвертация AVI,MPG в FLV на сервере.

Tags: php

Добрый день! Проблема при конвертации из AVI в FLV.

```
<?php
    $input = "video.avi";
    $output = "video.flv";
   $ffmpeg = new ffmpeg_movie($input);
    system("ffmpeg -i $input -ar 44100 -f flv $output");
?>
```

Вызов system и ffmpeg происходит, потому что если указать неправильное имя в **$input**, то php ругается, мол, файл не найден. Однако, файл video.flv не создаётся. В чём косяк, не пойму! И что лучше, FLV или SWF?

Comment: В смысле, Вы передаете в `$input` несуществующее имя файла и хотите чтобы что-то (`video.flv`) все равно появилось?

Answer (score 1):

1. Выполните в терминале команду `ffmpeg -i source -ar 44100 -f flv target`.
2. Выполните предыдущую команду от того же пользователя, что и скрипт, и в той же папке.
3. Выполните скрипт при полном пути к ffmpeg и при правах на папку записи 777.

Comment: А как запустить терминал(командную строку) на локальном сервере?Использую Denwer+Apache - это же не чистый *nix.

Answer (score 0):

проверьте открыта ли папка, куда вы хотите сохранить файл, для записи.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно писать команды прямо в php-скрипт. exec() возвращает текст (ответ о результате выполнения команды)